# Why do "for of" loop behave very strangely?

Tags: javascript, web

This behaviour is very strangely. I tested this code without "For of" loop and that was good.
What problem does it have?

It’s supposed to count unique elements.

```js
function countIdentic(arr) {
  let sum = 0
  let counter = 1
  for (let a of arr) {
    if (arr.includes(a, counter)) {
      sum++
      counter++
    }
  }
  return sum
}
let mf = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10]

console.log(countIdentic(mf))
```

[Displays wrong value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB4zQ.png)

What the thing?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do. What do sum and counter mean?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, **tell other readers what the expected behavior should be**. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: This just seems to get the length of the array

Comment: @EthanO'Brien It’s supposed to count unique elements. Or the non-unique ones, or so.

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Because `counter` is `1` it skips the first and last element in `arr` (`arr.includes(a, counter)`). Any other element can be found, hence we end with `8` + `1` (from before the loop) -> `9`

Comment: @SebastianSimon, in this example all of them are unique.

Comment: @EthanO'Brien It's actually length-1

Comment: I play with it. I expect that this code looks for the same values but it dowsnt work. In this example all values are unique and the code must return 0 but it returns 9. It just count them. What i did wrong?

Comment: @CarlParker Go through your code step by step, either by hand or with a debugger. Alternatively, just use `arr.length - new Set(arr).size` to count how many times any value repeats.

Comment: I got it. Thank you guys. And sorry for stupid ques

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that your counter needs to be incremented in every iteration, not only when the `if` statement is `true`. So pass it to the line below.

```js
function countIdentic(arr) {
let sum = 0
let counter=1
for(let a of arr){
  
  if(arr.includes(a,counter)){
    sum++;
  }
  counter++;
}
  return sum
}
let mf=[9,8,7,6,5,6,5,4,3,2,1,10]

console.log(countIdentic(mf))
```

Comment: Thank You. I am just a noobie